# Show the count up timer result on the page

Tags: javascript, html

i want to take out the result of the count up timer and show it on the page by clicking on button.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is a very basic javascript task.

Comment: You can use Local Storage to save result and reuse it when a user revisit it. If this is what you want as question is unclear.

Comment: thanks, i will make the question clear .

Comment: i want to take out the result of the count up timer and show it on the page by clicking on  button.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution for your problem,
I just made a simple counter and then each time I trigger the click event it will show the current timer value

The code:

```js
//initialisation
var counterLabel = document.getElementById("counter");
var valueLabel = document.getElementById("value");
var totalSeconds = 0;
counterLabel.innerHTML = totalSeconds;
//the loop each 1s
setInterval(setTime, 1000);

//the function that will increase the conter value and save it into the cookie
function setTime() {
  ++totalSeconds;
  counterLabel.innerHTML = totalSeconds;
}

//to get the current conter value
function getTime() {
  valueLabel.innerHTML = totalSeconds;
}
```

```html
<label id="counter"></label>
<button onclick="getTime()">save</button>
<label id="value"></label>
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/871t3w2o/3/

You can also have a look into [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and [sessionstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) they both work like the cookie but each one has it own advantages and disadvantages and you should choose the one that satisfy your need

Comment: thanks sir but you do not understand me, i want to take out the result of the count up timer and show it on the page by clicking on  button ,forgive me sir my english laungauge is so bad